# replacing images on click in javascript using php code for wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

First time posting to stack overflow. Apologies if I'm not following correct conventions.

I'm creating a site with a navigation menu that fades in when you click an icon.

When the menu fades in the icon should change to another icon in the shape of an `X` so that when the user wants to close the menu they click again and the navigation fades out.

The image source uses php code to locate the image and for whatever reason with the code I have it gives me one of those image not found icons on click and also an image not found icon when it's clicked again which is odd because it should change the code back to what it originally was (when the site initially loads the menu.svg comes up fine).

The images are in the right place in the site directory. Anyone have any insight?

Thanks so much

```js
window.onload = () => {

  const toggleTag = document.querySelector("a.toggle-nav")
  const navTag = document.querySelector("nav")

  toggleTag.addEventListener("click", function () {
    navTag.classList.toggle("open")

    if (navTag.classList.contains("open")) {
      toggleTag.innerHTML = '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/close.svg">'
    } else {
      toggleTag.innerHTML = '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/menu.svg">'
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the image element, and see what is the full path to the image source? I suggest you to double check if the path is really correct and if you can locate to that image manually.

Comment: I looked and it looks like it was treating the php code as if it was a part of the url and was spitting out http://secondhand.local/<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/close.svg as the source and not running the php to get the directory. I just replaced the php code with the directory fully written out and it's working.

Comment: Where is this written? Is it in functions.php for your theme?

Comment: In a separate javascript file then added into the site in the functions.php file using wp_enqueue_script

Comment: You have to run it  inside .php file, javascript files are not processed even if it contains some PHP code, you need to use get_template_directory_uri() function from the right places where it is accessible. Basically it should be accessible anywhere in your theme code.

Comment: @Erasus gotcha good to know. Thanks :)

Comment: The proper way to supply an external JavaScript with a few dynamic values determined in PHP, would be https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

Comment: @CBroe you should post that as an answer! Then I could have upvoted it